# Time Complexity of a iterative program

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    for (int j = 1; j <= i*i; j++)
        if (j % i ==0)
            for (int k = 0; k < j k++)
                sum++;
```

I am trying to find out time complexity of this above program.

First "for loop" will run n times.

Second for loop will execute overall n^3 times

The innermost loop will execute when j is multiple of i, that will happen exactly i times.

Please help me to find the overall time complexity of this program.

Comment: This is not a recursive program.

Comment: oh sorry! it's iterative program

Comment: Please do not use images when you could use text instead.

Comment: Your question already contains the start of a good answer; but you just stop in the middle. Why did you get stuck? What are you uncertain about?

Comment: sure, no it's not duplicate of that question.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I am unable to conclude the overall time complexity

Comment: shouldn't it be O(n^4) ?

Comment: yes, it is O(n^4) but how? explain in details @A.Rashad

Comment: Somewhere here (cs.stackexchange) I have seen exactly the same question asking runtime of exactly the same program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times that the `if` statement is executed is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \Theta(n^3).
$$
The number of times that `sum` is incremented is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j'=1}^i ij' = \sum_{i=1}^n i \sum_{j'=1}^i j' = \sum_{i=1}^n \Theta(i^3) = \Theta(n^4).
$$
Here $j' = j/i$, and the reason we are allowed to do this is that the inner loop gets executed only when $j'$ is integral.

We get that overall, the running time is $\Theta(n^4)$.

Answer (score -1):

The rule to calculate time complexity is to measure how many times (at most) will your code run compared to input.
in our case, we have the input as *n*

the outermost loop runs *n* times, so this loop has a complexity of *O(n)*, assuming code inside this loop is static.

Then comes next level, a loop that explicitly run *n<sup>2</sup>* times, that makes an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* piece of code.

Then we have an `if` block, that would have a complexity _O(1) because it would not scale on *n* size

and finally, a loop that runs *j* times; *j* has an upper bound of *n<sup>2</sup>* , that should make the inner most loop of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*

That makes the overall complexity = *n* × *n<sup>2</sup>* × *n<sup>2</sup>* =  *n<sup>5</sup>* i.e. *O(n<sup>5</sup>)*  not *O(n<sup>4</sup>)*

Comment: While $O(n^5)$ is true, an even better upper bound is $O(n^4)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus are your relying on prior knowledge of the modulus operator to trim complexity by n?

Comment: What do you mean by "prior knowledge"? We all know what the modulus operator does, it's part of the semantics of C.

Comment: True, I didn't think it over to eliminate values of j % i != 0

Comment: "how many times (at most) will your code run compared to input." It'll run once...